# fatal: not a git repository:'git'

Tags: git, https, ssh

I use git+bitbucket as my version control system.

When I do `git push -u origin master` (`origin` uses https), I get:

```
fatal: not a git repository: 'git'
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

My version of git bash is 1.7.10.  My OS is Win7.

To my surprise, if I use SSH protocol, I can push.  I think there is some trouble with my https or my computer environment.

Comment: Can you fetch from it? If not, then the remote URL is probably not correct.

Answer (score 0):

In most ways you cannot push over **https**. For this you need some more. In most way you push over **ssh** or the **git** protocoll because then you have enough rights to the git files.

Normally you get the message not a git repository when this folder where you are have no **.git** folder. But then its very strange that you can push over ssh.

Second ways is you get the message when the remote Repo is not there and he cannot find the bare file on the remote server. This is possible when you try it over **https**.

Comment: I can push successfully in my friend's computer over https.....but,can not with my computer..

Comment: Have you checked the configurations? Normally you need an extra configutation for https. But you mean you can push to his computer but he cannot push to your mashine correct?

Comment: no...It is,I can use my friend's computer to  do the clone and push operation successfully.

Comment: I didn't config the https in my friend's computer,but i can push successfully

Comment: Perhaps you don't have the certificated to access over https? Have you blocked the port? Perhaps you can make a telnet to the address and port 443?

Comment: Perhaps you can make a telnet to the address and port 443?  How I can do that,I'm a newcomer。。

Comment: when SSH is available then you should use it :) SSH is a encrypted connection the same as https in most cases better. So when its working over SSH you can use it.